# How can I find an element by name in a XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse ICD-10 codes and given a code, identify: description, parent, children (if any). Given this sample of the larger file I'm parsing:

## A sample of the larger XML file I'm parsing

````
data = ```<diag>
<name>A00</name>
<desc>Cholera</desc>
<diag>
  <name>A00.0</name>
  <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
  <inclusionTerm>
    <note>Classical cholera</note>
  </inclusionTerm>
</diag>
<diag>
  <name>A00.1</name>
  <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</desc>
  <inclusionTerm>
    <note>Cholera eltor</note>
  </inclusionTerm>
</diag>
<diag>
  <name>A00.9</name>
  <desc>Cholera, unspecified</desc>
</diag>
</diag>```
````

How can I write a code in python that gives me the specific element by searching its name? (example: I'm looking for the code A00.0 and I want the program to print the found A00.0 code, plus the description and the inclusionTerm.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Have you tried anything? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mzjn mentioned, you can use `xml.etree`, which is part of the Python Standard Library. In particular, you may want to checkout [XPath Support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('myfile.xml')  # alternatively use ET.fromstring()

# Find diagnosis by "name" (ICD-10 code)
diag = root.find(".//*[name='A00.0']")

# Print out some information ("name" and "desc" tags)
print(diag.find('name').text)
print(diag.find('desc').text)
```

### Explanation of XPath `.//*[name='A00.0']`

- `.` select current node (XML root element)
- `//` select all subelements (search tree recursively)
- `*` select all child elements
- `[name='A00.0']` select element that has a child named `name` whose text is `A00.0`

So calling `root.find()` with this XPath finds this node:

```
<diag>
  <name>A00.0</name>
  <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
  <inclusionTerm>
    <note>Classical cholera</note>
  </inclusionTerm>
</diag>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I also include the printing of the 'inclusionTerm', specificaly the 'note' that's inside it?

Comment: Same way: `print(diag.find('inclusionTerm').find('node').text)`

Comment: That worked! :) But I still have some problems. What if, for example, there would be 2 'note' lines inside the Inclusion Term? something like: <inclusionTerm>
            <note>Botulism NOS</note>
            <note>Classical foodborne intoxication due to Clostridium botulinum</note>
          </inclusionTerm>      The code you helped me with only prints the first line. How can I print all the lines?